# Celery: am I misunderstanding how it's meant to work?

Tags: celery, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I have an EC2-based REST web service which is connected to a set of worker instances via SQS. I am hoping to replace this current setup with [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/), retaining (for the moment) SQS as the broker.

I am not sure my mental picture of how Celery operates is quite accurate, however. Following the pattern that seems to be implied in [this](http://blog.4psa.com/offloading-to-workers-a-hands-on-example/) article, my understanding was that I could enqueue messages to SQS from my API, and these would then be processed by the Celery workers in a timely fashion. The examples I have found, however (almost none of which involve using SQS as a broker), seem to indicate that Celery *itself* does the enqueuing. So Celery acts like a 'wrapper' for the queue, submitting and processing tasks. It's acting as both producer *and* consumer - is that right? If so that seems like a big problem for me, since I don't use Python. The workers themselves would use execl() to run the actual tasks, but how would I handle the initial submission of the message into the queue, from the API server? Is this something that Celery even allows?

Am I right about this, or was my original understanding accurate? Or are they equally legitimate ways in which Celery can be utilized?

Comment: [This](http://abhishek-tiwari.com/post/amqp-rabbitmq-and-celery-a-visual-guide-for-dummies/) article states that instead of Celery '[i]t is possible to use a different custom consumer (worker) or producer (client).'

Answer (score 1):

The protocol Celery uses for messages is well [documented](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html). You can implement a custom producer in any language or use one of the existing implementations (PHP, Node.js, Ruby, etc.). They are listed [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/introduction.html#what-is-a-task-queue).

Also you can use [web hooks](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html#guide-webhooks) which allows to call tasks from any environment.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, I was thinking of using web hooks. But isn't that getting things round the wrong way - isn't it Celery that calls the web hook, through a request to the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Re: how to conceptualize Celery, I think of it as an asynchronous programming framework (although it is possible to use it synchronously). Identifying a function as a Celery `Task` decorates your function with async operations, like `.delay()` and `.apply_async()`, and returns you an `AsyncResult` for checking execution and status. It happens to use RabbitMQ as the default broker to manage it's internal async processing. By default it acts as both the producer and consumer of the queued tasks.

As long as you adhere to the protocol you can write your own Celery producer or consumer against RabbitMQ or the broker of your choice. A decent visual explanation of the relationship between RabbitMQ and Celery can be found [here](http://abhishek-tiwari.com/post/amqp-rabbitmq-and-celery-a-visual-guide-for-dummies).